# How to write the different variable value in a file in TCL

Tags: file, tcl

How to write the different variable value in TCL using the foreach loop.
Here this is the situation:

```
set data1 "This is Data1 Value\n"
set data2  "This is Data2 Value"
set data3  "\nThis is Data3 Value\n"

foreach different_content {data1 data2 data3} {

  puts $fo $different_content
}
close $fo
}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with the fragment of code.  The first and simplest error is that you have not anywhere opened the file `fo`.  Unless that is done elsewhere in code you haven't shown here, you need to add something like

```
set fo [open test.txt w]
```

before your `foreach` loop.

The second problem is that your code is going to write this content to the file:

```
data1
data2
data3
```

but probably you intend for it to write this content:

```
This is Data1 Value

This is Data2 Value

This is Data3 Value
```

Here the error is more subtle.  What your loop is doing is setting `different_content` to the *name* of each variable of interest, but you want the *value* of those variables.  Essentially you need to doubly dereference the `different_content` variable.  Adding a `$` at the start of the variable name gives you one level of dereferencing.  Unfortunately with Tcl, you can't just slap another `$` onto the front to get the second level.  But you can use the `set` command.  After all, `$` is just syntacic sugar for `set`:  `$foo` is identical to `[set foo]`.  Therefore, I believe you need to rewrite the body of your loop as follows:

```
puts $fo [set $different_content]
```

So, putting it all together:

```
set data1 "This is Data1 Value\n"
set data2  "This is Data2 Value"
set data3  "\nThis is Data3 Value\n"

set fo [open test.txt w]
foreach different_content {data1 data2 data3} {
    puts $fo [set $different_content]
}
close $fo
```

Comment: Really u r great man. Thanks. U understood my exact problem and give me exact suggestion and it is working fine. Thank u so much..

Comment: If he answered your question, you should accept his answer. It looks like you've asked a number of different questions but not accepted any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Eric's answer is great, but there's two other ways to write that foreach loop:

Method 1 (read the variables earlier):

```
foreach different_content [list $data1 $data2 $data3] {
    puts $fo $different_content
}
```

Method 2 (use `upvar 0` to make named aliases to variables):

```
foreach different_var {data1 data2 data3} {
    upvar 0 $different_var different_content
    puts $fo $different_content
}
```

Comment: Or, store the data in a different data structure at the start

Comment: @glenn: Yes. Using an (associative) array makes lots of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the filehandle you are referring to as `$fo` but have not actually opened:

```
set data1 "This is Data1 Value\n"
set data2  "This is Data2 Value"
set data3  "\nThis is Data3 Value\n"

set fo [open 'test.txt']

foreach different_content {data1 data2 data3} {
  puts $fo $different_content
}

close $fo
```

Comment: See My code dear   proc testforeach {} {

set filename /tmp/indrajeet_DBTEST_dbmode.sql
set data1 "This is data1 value\n"
set data2  "This is data2 value"

set fo open('/tmp/indrajeet_DBTEST_dbmode.sql')


foreach different_content {data1 data2} {

  puts $fo $different_content
}
close $fo
}

testforeach   But it is not working dear, Please help me.

Comment: Note: Here i want to write file in a specific location i.e. within the temp folder.

Comment: but u also wrote the same syntax in u r code. set fo open('name of the file'), so is it correct or not. please....

Comment: set fo [open $filename w]    So this syntax is correct or not please tell me

Comment: @galvin you are welcome  @slebetman The point was he forgot to open the filehandle so his problem was solved even if my tcl is rusty.